Java Hibernate Date Comparison
I am facing an issue in comparing a date in java CriteriaQuery.
Date which is stored in a database is in this format
01-Jan-90 12:00:00.123456789 AM

How shall I convert this string "01-Jan-90 12:00:00.123456789 AM" in date format?
I'm trying to convert this String into LocalDateTime format but I'm unable to do so.
Can someone help me?

Does your database use a text field, such as varchar, to store dates?

Is that date String about the 20th or 21st century? I'm talking about the 90… Is it the year 1990 or 2090?

Always specify a Locale with a date-time formatter for custom formats.

You can use DateTimeFormatter and LocalDateTime.parse to solve problem:
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MMM-yy hh:mm:ss.n a", Locale.ENGLISH);
LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(dateStr, formatter);

Note that using Locale.ENGLISH ensures correct parsing for English month names like "Jan"

Thanks it got worked. I was missing  that Locale.ENGLISH
